# What would cause a popover component to fail when popover directives work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, popover, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to use BootstrapVue's popovers. As far as I can tell I am importing everything I need

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" 
                 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
           integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" 
           crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-vue@2.7.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.common.min.js"
           integrity="sha256-NTImazhsLEaQ0a59ZMLLxaOfFnKZNLJbbTcZh9YBM58="
           crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I can get popovers to work with

```
<div id="general-info" class="questionMarkHelp" v-b-popover.hover.bottom="'På denna sida kan du se en sammanställning av statistik för din kommun'">
```

But when I try to use b-popover, it doesn't work

```
<font-awesome-icon id="investigations" icon="question-circle" size="2x"/>
<b-popover target="investigations" placement="bottom" triggers="hover">
           Här kan du statistik över utredningar.<br>
           Du kan se hur många utredningar din kommun har.<br>
           Hur många som är pågående.<br>
           Hur många som ledde till insats.<br>
           Hur många som inte ledde till insats
</b-popover>
```

As you can see, I would like to be able to format the text inside the popover with 
 tags. Otherwise I would probably just be content with using the directive type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `Bootstrap-Vue`, you do NOT need to import `jQuery`, `popper` and `bootstrap.js`. You can read what you need to import [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs#browser).

The only thing you need to import from bootstrap is their CSS/SCSS. (You can still import `jQuery` and `popper` if you use them for something else, but it's not required)

Everything else i handled by the Vue specific components from `Bootstrap-Vue`.

Your code works fine, if i don't import the unnecessary files, as you can see in the snippet below. (I've replaced your font-awesome-icon with the Bootstrap-Vue icon component, this shouldn't make a difference).

Another thing to note is that the `v-b-popover` directive supports the `html` modifier to format the string you pass in as HTML.

**Edit:** 
It looks like `bootstrap-vue.common.min.js` doesn't support the `b-popover` component, switching it to import `bootstrap-vue.min.js` instead fixed the component.

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data() {
  return {
    text: "Här kan du statistik över utredningar.<br>Du kan se hur många utredningar din kommun har.<br>Hur många som är pågående.<br>Hur många som ledde till insats.<br>Hur många som inte ledde till insats"
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.7.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>

<!-- Import Vue and Bootstrap-Vue Javascript-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-vue@2.7.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Only imported for this example -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>



<div id="app" class="container">
  <!-- Using the directive with the HTML modifier  -->
  <b-icon v-b-popover.html.hover.bottom="text" icon="question"></b-icon>
  
  <!-- Using the component -->
  <b-icon id="investigations" icon="info"></b-icon>
  <b-popover target="investigations" placement="bottom" triggers="hover">
    <span v-html="text"></span>
  </b-popover>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Removing the unneeded imports didn't seem to change anything, but the html modifier worked perfectly.

Comment: @JimiWindmills You might want to check the `edit` i added. I think that's the root cause of your issue.

Comment: oh thanks, I hadn't noticed that. I'll check it out.

Comment: The ESM/commonjs builds do not include the popper, etc, dependencies.  The browser build (UMD) does include the required dependencies popper, etc. https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs#dependencies